# what if condition to put in php code

Tags: php, mysql, html, audio

I have made a voice dictionary. The user inputs a word and the corresponding meaning is fetched from my sql database , it is displayed on screen and then converted to speech.Its working all fine.

I just want to add one condition that : If user enters a word that is not present in my database then  it outputs the message " sorry word not found",  and nothing should be played in the audio. 
Currently if i enter a word which is not present , i am getting the audio of 'undefined index..something.. '

plz tell me where to add the if condition and what to add
Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Word meanings</title> 
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "abcd");
mysql_select_db("dictionary");
if(isset($_POST['Submit1']))

{

 $req=$_REQUEST['word'];
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dict WHERE word='$req'";
 $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
 {
  $x=$row["word"];
  $y=$row["meaning"];
  $z=$row["synonym"];
  echo "<b>Word</b>: " . $x ."<br/>" ;
  echo "<b>Meaning</b>: " . $y ."<br/>" ;
  echo "<b>Synonym</b>: " . $z ."<br/>" ;
 }
}


mysql_close();
?>

</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="lastry.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="word" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['word'])?$_POST['word']:''?>"x-webkit-speech/>
<Input Type ="Submit" Name ="Submit1" Value ="submit"> 
</form>
<?php  
if($_POST)
{
?>

<p>Listen word 
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="http://speechutil.com/convert/ogg?text='<?php echo urlencode($x);?>'"    &type="audio/mp3" />

</audio>
</p>
<br><br>

<p>Listen meaning 
<audio controls="controls">


<source src="http://speechutil.com/convert/ogg?text='<?php echo urlencode($y);?>" &type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</p>
<br><br>
<p>Listen synonym
<audio controls="controls">

<source src="http://speechutil.com/convert/ogg?text='<?php echo urlencode($z);?>'" &type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
</p>
<?php 
}

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obligatory Suggestion, [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately after `$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);`, add the line `$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($rs);`, then you can have:

```
if($num_rows > 0) {
    /*Run while loop which you already have*/
}
else {
    echo 'Sorry word not found';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe check if it has value in it

```
 if( isset($_POST) && !empty($x) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Add counter to here:

```
 $foundwords = 0;    
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
 {
  $x=$row["word"];
  $y=$row["meaning"];
  $z=$row["synonym"];
  echo "<b>Word</b>: " . $x ."<br/>" ;
  echo "<b>Meaning</b>: " . $y ."<br/>" ;
  echo "<b>Synonym</b>: " . $z ."<br/>" ;
  $foundwords++;  // increase counter after each found word
 }
```

and then later after `mysql_close()` check that variable (somewhere inside the body)

```
if($foundwords==0) { 
  echo 'sorry word not found';
  ... finish html etc ...
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this :

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['Submit1']) {
      mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "abcd");
      mysql_select_db("dictionary");

      $req=$_REQUEST['word'];
      $rs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM dict WHERE word='$req'");

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
        $x=$row["word"];
        $y=$row["meaning"];
        $z=$row["synonym"];
        echo "<b>Word</b>: " . $x ."<br/>" ;
        echo "<b>Meaning</b>: " . $y ."<br/>" ;
        echo "<b>Synonym</b>: " . $z ."<br/>" ;
     }
     if (!isset($x)) { $All_Find = $req; } else { $All_Find = true; }

   }
?>

<?php if ($All_Find == true) { ?>
<audio controls="controls">
<source src="http://speechutil.com/convert/ogg?text='<?php echo urlencode($y);?>" &type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<?php } else { echo "Sorry, the world $All_Find cannot be found :(";}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The undefined index message is mainly the result of your php.ini settings. If you turn of Notice are Warning error levels there. The value of a no existing associative array member in php is always NULL ( = false = '' ).

If you want to be exact however, you could check like this

```
// the condition evaluates to false if $row has no 'meaning' member
if($row['meaning'])
   $z = $row['meaning'];
else
   $z = "sorry word not found";
```